# Написать CSS свойство только для Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css, javascript

Internet Explorer 10 не поддерживает условные комментарии. Как написать CSS св-во только для Internet Explorer 10? Может можно как то через jquery? Помогите пожалуйста!

Мне нужно поправить ширину элемента Explorer 10.

```
#content {
    width:980px;
    margin:20px auto 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<head>

     <script> if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { 
                    var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML; 
                    headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie10.css">'; 
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML; 
                    } 
        </script>
</head>
```

создаете `ie10.css`

и в нем прописываете нужные свойства

незабудьте правильно путь к файлу ie10.css прописать

Comment: Для таких целей условные [комментарии существуют][1]

   [1]:http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/internet-explorer/uslovnye-kommentarii

Comment: для IE10 условные комментарии не работают

Comment: @Deonis, в ИЕ10 условные комментарии уже не поддерживаются

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: Можно обойтись без скриптов.

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий пример на **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7QP2/)**

**html**

```
<div id="test">You will see it only in IE10</div>
```

**css**

```
#test {
    color: white;
}

/* Только для IE 10 */
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   #test {
       background-color: green;       
    }
}
```